# php cli daemon unable to get logs

Tags: php, linux, logging, command-line-interface

I run an endless php script (loop) as a daemon like this :

`start-stop-daemon --start --background --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/process.pid --exec /usr/bin/php /var/www/script.php >> /var/log/process.log`

It works great but sometimes it crashes and I'm unable to find any logs.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with php5.

I've tried to edit my /etc/php5/cli/php.ini with the folowing values but in vain :

`display_errors = On`

`log_errors = On`

`error_log = /var/log/php5-cli.log`

Nothing is added to /var/log/process.log or /var/log/php5-cli.log

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the user run PHP CLI has access to `/var/log/php5-cli.log`

Comment: The user that's run the daemon is the root user.